# WebStorm debug mode not working and get message Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, protractor, webstorm

I have recently downloaded WebStorm 11.0.3 to run my Protractor test cases. My test cases run fine when run normally (i.e. run from run configurations) but when I try to run my test cases in debug mode nothing really happens and I get the following in the console:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=58467 --nolazy c:\Users\daobrien15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js conf.js
Debugger listening on port 58467
Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

When I run debug against Firefox it just launches the first run Firefox screen and does nothing. When I run it against Chrome it just loads a blank page with `data:,` in the URL bar and also does nothing.

I am using the following:

> OS: Win 7 (64 bit)
>
> Protractor: 3.0.0
>
> Selenium webdriver: 2.48.2
>
> Firefox: 35 as the latest was not working with my tests when run normally
>
> Chrome: 47.0.2526.111 m (Latest)

Also I am running my selenium **webmanager** through the console. I get pretty much the same result if I use the **directConnect** option in my **conf.js** file:

```
directConnect: true,
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what node.js version do you use? si ilar issues were reported against some unstable node 0.11 versions.

Comment: My npm version is 3.5.3 and my node.js version is 5.3.0

Comment: please see the answer below. Does upgrading Node.js help?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Me environment is down at the moment but I will check it as soon as it's back up

Comment: This seems to have solved that issue but unfortunately has created a new one. When I run debug mode now it just seems to hang when it reaches a break point. It doesn't give me the option to step over, step into etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had same problem.
Check version of node.js in your webstorm terminal: `node --version`
My version was 5.2 and I had this bug.
Today I update node to 5.5.0(last stable) and this problem gone.

NOTE: If you use Webstorm 9 or 10 go to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0\bin`

and open `WebStorm64.exe.vmoptions` and `WebStorm.exe.vmoption`s and in the end set

`-Dnodejs.debugger.use.jb.support=false`

this will help to stop on your breakpoint.
If you use Webstorm 11 you will not have this problem, but if you will - use fix for WebStorm 9/10.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: for me the solution was: update node 4.2.6 to 4.4.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problem. I was tried @user3552 solution but not worked for me second time. I checked my node params and removed this param from my node params. This is working now.

```
--debug-brk=8081
```

Before removing one param my exec code was like this

```
 /home/veysel/.nave/installed/5.0.0/bin/node --debug-brk=37621 -debug-brk=8081 --expose_debug_as=v8debug /opt/lampp/htdocs/kart/server.js 8080
```

After removing the last exec code like this.

```
  /home/veysel/.nave/installed/5.0.0/bin/node --debug-brk=37621 --expose_debug_as=v8debug /opt/lampp/htdocs/kart/server.js 8080
```